# How can I remove a folder but not the content inside it?

Tags: python, directory

Imagine I have a folder (`Folder_1`), and inside it there is another folder (`Folder_2`) where I placed some songs documents etc.

Is there a way I can remove the second folder but keep all the documents and songs in the upper folder (`Folder_1`)?

Comment: Move the content before removing the parent folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use `shutil.move()` to move files from one path to another:

```
import os
from glob import glob
from shutil import move

f1 = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder_1'
f2 = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder_1\Folder_2'

for f in glob(f2+'//*'):
    move(f, os.path.join(f1, os.path.basename(f)))
    
os.rmdir(f2)
```

#### UPDATE:

You can also leave out the `glob` module, and just use `os` and `shutil`:

```
from os import listdir, rmdir
from shutil import move

f1 = r'C:\Users\Caitlin\Desktop\Folder_1'
f2 = 'Folder_2'

for f in listdir(f"{f1}/{f2}"):
    print(f)
    move(f"{f1}/{f2}/{f}", f"{f1}/{f}")
    
rmdir(f"{f1}/{f2}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```py
import os
import shutil

# move everything from folder 2 into folder 1
for i in os.listdir("[Folder_2 path]"):
    shutil.move(os.path.join("[Folder_2 path]", i), "[Folder_1 path]")
# remove the now empty folder
os.rmdir("[Folder_2 path]")
```

Comment: This moves the entire directory, not just its contents.